# aspect-ratio setting to fill the space

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, aspect-ratio

what should I be using to make sure there is no space left (please see attached image)?

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
    video: {
    width: '100%',
    margin:'1%',
    aspectRatio: 16 /9,
  }, });
```

this is in react-native

[image]

Comment: No space left where, in the vertical direction?

Comment: sorry my bad I meant I want to fill all space with the video itself, so as you can see in screenshot the black part below video that I do not want .

Comment: and yes in vertical direction